# Why does StringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens return true when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have this code:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (line, String.valueOf(delimiter));

labels.add("Time");

int currentCol = 1;                                                 
while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
  st.nextToken();
  labels.add(new String("c" + currentCol++));                                
}
```

Where `delimiter` is `;` and line is `0.6245`.

Why do I end up with an `ArrayList` `labels` that has it's second element `c1`? While the documentation says:

> Tests if there are more tokens available from this tokenizer's string. If this method returns true, then a subsequent call to nextToken with no argument will successfully return a token.
>
> Returns:
>
> **true** if and only if there is at least one token in the string after the current position; **false** otherwise.

Since value: `0.6245` cannot be split by delimiter `;` why would `hasMoreTokens()` return `true`?

**EDIT:**

Now I understand why `while` loop get's to execute at least once. It is because that is the way `StringTokenizer` works. Rather than regular `split` that I am used to where I can access any position of the resulting `array`, here the only way to access elements is with the `nextElement()` method. Which means that even if there is only one element in the `StringTokenizer` it will always return `true` from `hasMoreTokens()`.

The reason why I am wondering about `StringTokenizer` which is what I learned a legacy class is that I am reviewing an old code that I am about to reuse.

Comment: Print the tokens and check if it's the right values.

Comment: You should read a bit more from the documentation: *"A token is a maximal sequence of consecutive characters that are not delimiters"*. So if the delimiter cannot be found, then the whole supplied string is one token. (The same applies to `String#split`; in case you like to use that instead)

Comment: Also _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for
 * compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code.It is
 * recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split
 * method of Stringor the java.util.regex package instead._

Comment: It's strange, when I print anything within the while loop, it doesn't execute (which is expected), but why then when I debug, my arraylist has that c1 value? I will check it further, I am missing something.

Comment: @Tom, I know that the whole string is one token if delimiter is not found, but that is the only one, there is no next token, right? So I would expect `hasMoreTokens` to be false as there is only 1 token...

Comment: *"when I print anything within the while loop, it doesn't execute"* When there is a problem with that test. The `while` loop iterates one time (tested it myself). About the other comment: you need to consider the current position. After creating the tokenizer, the reading position is on "0". Then you ask "do you have more tokens?", when it will find the whole supplied String, returns that and  advances the position "pointer". The next question for more tokens will then be `false`.

Comment: Makes sense, the only thing that doesn't make sense to me is why when it asks "do you have more tokens?" it says it does, when there is only one token. But if the reading position is on "0" maybe that's why. But then what element is on the 0th position in the `StringTokenizer`?

Comment: *"But then what element is on the 0th position in the StringTokenizer"* I guess it works internally like Strings `substring`. Index 0 is the position before the first letter. Index 3 would then be the position between letter 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you are adding an element on your list outside your loop:

```
labels.add("Time");
```

**You have just one token after the Tokenize works**. That's because when you tokenize a String that hasn't the informed delimiter you have only one element, so if your string is `0.6245` understand it as tokens as (for your delimiter):

```
First token: 0.6245
Second token: nothing
```

It is like if it was: `0.6245;`

Inside your loop you are adding another thing to your array list:

```
labels.add(new String("c" + currentCol++));
```

Since you initialized `currentCol` as `1` and the `while` will run just once it will have the `c1` as value on the second element of your list (remember, you have added one before)

I don't know what are you trying to achieve. But it seems like you want something like:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (line, String.valueOf(delimiter));

//Don't add this:
//labels.add("Time");

int currentCol = 1;                                                 
while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String someThing = st.nextToken();
    labels.add(new String("Current token:" + someThing 
                   + "\n currentCol: " + currentCol++));                                
}
```

Comment: You are completely right and thank you for your answer. I was just wondering why is `hasMoreTokens` returning true if as you stated second token is nothing? It's not a do-while loop... and the condition wasn't met.

Comment: It is not that it returns nothing, When it enters in the while loop it is on the first position. But your list `labels` in your code already have one element, therefore the `c1` on position two. When you call `st.nextToken()` only then it moves to the second element that is nonexistent so it exits the while after it finishes.

Comment: But if `StringTokenizer` has only one element why `st.hasMoreTokens()` returns `true`? Maybe that is the standard behavior but it doesn't make sense to me, if there is only one token then there is no more tokens... Anyway I give you +1 for trying to explain that to me.

Comment: @OndrejTokar It has 1 token, and since you haven't retrieved that token yet, [`hasMoreTokens()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreTokens%28%29) ("*Tests if there are more tokens available*") returns true. On the first (and only) iteration of the loop, you then retrieve that token by calling [`nextToken()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken%28%29) ("*Returns the next token*"), you throw it away and add `"c1"` to `labels`. *Then* `hasMoreTokens()` return false, and loop exits.

Comment: @Andreas yes, that answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: @OndrejTokar It works the exact same way as an `Iterator` and an `Enumeration`. In fact, it *is* an `Enumeration`, so I'm unsure why you had trouble understanding the behavior in the first place.

Comment: @Andreas for some reason my mind stuck to the `split` and I expected the same behavior for some reason... Can't tell.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas to answer him. I was not at my computer to continue explaining his questions. :)

Comment: @OndrejTokar this should be the accepted answer, since it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

**0.6245** is itself a token though you don't have a delimiter. 
If you would have something like this **"0.6245;0.987"** then it has 2 tokens. Unless your **line** has an empty space or a null value while loop will be entered at least once.

Comment: You get `NullPointerException` if `line` is null, but you are correct that empty string will return no tokens.